# Wie werden die (modischen) Flicken an Ärmeln bezeichnet?

Tags: single-word-request

Ich beobachte in jüngster Zeit einen Modetrend hin zu diesen Flicken an dem Ärmeln, auf Höhe der Ellenbogen, rückseitig.

Haben diese Flicken einen besonderen Namen, abgesehen von "ovale Flicken am Ärmel"?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Genau genommen ist die Antwort:

Die **modischen** Flicken am Ellbogen heißen "**Patches**". Sie haben offenbar ausschließlich ästhetische  Funktion. <sup>[hierzu könnte man noch so manches sagen...]</sup>

Aber das Ganze gab's ja schon mal - viele von uns mussten diese Dinger als Kind verkraften:

Die **altmodischen** Flicken am Ellbogen heißen "**Lederflicken**" (weil meist aus Leder) oder einfach "Flicken", teilweise auch "Flecken". Sie haben primär die Funktion, schadhafte Stellen zu verdecken oder eben typische Verschleißstellen zu schützen - klassischerweise Knie und Ellbogen.